# python max function using 'key' and lambda expression on dictionary with list elements

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, key, max

In Python, I want to find a specific dictionary key, based on the value, but the value is a list.

For example:

```
    dicti = {"TP50":[1,5],"TP02":[2,6],"TP33":[7,2],"TP4":[6,3]}
    print(max(dicti, key=dicti.get))
```

This will print "TP33"

How can I modify they key so that it will return "TP02", meaning the max value, when the second element in each item's list is considered?

Perhaps something like this?

```
    print(max(dicti, key=lambda x: ... ))
```

Some other examples:

```
    print(max(dicti)) # This will print TP50
    print(max(dicti, key=dicti.get)) # This will print TP33
```

Now what would I need to write to have it print TP02, where TP02 is they key with the largest second element in its value list?

Comment: Key=lambda x: dict1[x][1]

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer, using the lambda function:

```
    inventory = {'apple':(3, 133), 'banana':(9, 407), 'pear':(17, 205), 'orange':(1, 91)}
    print(max(inventory.keys(), key=(lambda k: inventory[k][1])))
```

This will print "banana"

In the same fashion, this would print "TP02":

```
    print(max(dicti.keys(), key=(lambda k: dicti[k][1])))
```

Some more examples:

```
    inventory = {'Apple':(3, 133, 'AZ'), 'Banana':(9, 407, 'BY'), 'Pear':(17, 205, 'CX'), 'Raspberry':(1, 91, 'DW')}

    print("\nSorting keys:")
    print(max(inventory.keys()))                                      #sort by key
    print(max(inventory.keys(), key=(lambda k: k)))                   #sort by key
    print(max(inventory.keys(), key=(lambda k: k[0])))                #sort by key, first letter
    print(max(inventory.keys(), key=(lambda k: k[1])))                #sort by key, second letter
    print(max(inventory.keys(), key=inventory.get))                   #sort by value
    print(max(inventory.keys(), key=(lambda k: inventory[k])))        #sort by value
    print(max(inventory.keys(), key=(lambda k: inventory[k][2][1])))  #sort by value, third item, second letter
    print(max(inventory.keys(), key=(lambda k: inventory[k][0])))     #sort by value, first item
    print(max(inventory.keys(), key=(lambda k: inventory[k][1])))     #sort by value, second item
    print(max(inventory.keys(), key=(lambda k: inventory[k][2])))     #sort by value, third item

    print("\nSorting items:")
    print(max(inventory.items()))                                     #sort by item
    print(max(inventory.items(), key=(lambda item: item[0])))         #sort by key
    print(max(inventory.items(), key=(lambda item: item[0][0])))      #sort by key (first letter)
    print(max(inventory.items(), key=(lambda item: item[0][1])))      #sort by key (second letter)
    print(max(inventory.items(), key=(lambda item: item[1])))         #sort by value
    print(max(inventory.items(), key=(lambda item: item[1][0])))      #sort by value, first item
    print(max(inventory.items(), key=(lambda item: item[1][1])))      #sort by value, second item
    print(max(inventory.items(), key=(lambda item: item[1][2])))      #sort by value, third item
    print(max(inventory.items(), key=(lambda item: item[1][2][1])))   #sort by value, third item, second letter

    print("\nSorting values:")
    print(max(inventory.values()))                                    #sort by value
    print(max(inventory.values(), key=(lambda val: val)))             #sort by value
    print(max(inventory.values(), key=(lambda val: val[0])))          #sort by value, first item
    print(max(inventory.values(), key=(lambda val: val[1])))          #sort by value, second item
    print(max(inventory.values(), key=(lambda val: val[2])))          #sort by value, third item
    print(max(inventory.values(), key=(lambda val: val[2][1])))       #sort by value, third item, second letter
```

Comment: Great contribution there, Sebastian.